# How to put application/x-mpegURL in source in videojs

Tags: javascript, django, video, video.js

I'm not JavaScript guy but I have project with js and plugin VIDEOJS (Video.js v4.6.4 Copyright 2014 Brightcove, Inc. https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/).

I recived an error:

> video.dev.js:1384 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)
>   The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network
>   failed or because the format is not supported.

I know that solved of this problem can be put: `<source src="video/test.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">.` but my question is, how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Original, but now outdated answer:

> For browsers without native HLS support you need the videojs-contrib-hls plugin: http://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/

As of Video.js v7, HLS is supported by default and does not require anything additional in the default build. HLS playback is either native (Safari, iOS) or Video.js's Media Source Extensions playback engine https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming, which replaced videojs-contrib-hls.

Comment: Hi, i am using videojs v7 and it doesn't work in IE11 on win7. Somebody can help me?

Comment: IE11 on Win7 does not have Media Source Extensions. You can use https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-flashls-source-handler to play HLS in Flash

Comment: @misterben I am using video.js 7.8.2 but still the video is not playing. When I refresh the video starts playing. This is wierd.

Comment: And `videojs-contrib-hls` is now depreciated and is now succeeded by `videojs-http-streaming (VHS)`